# Parameterize a trigger in a button to update a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger, ampscript, triggered-send

Is there any possibility parameterize a trigger to be included in a Button (in an email, built in Content Builder), to update a specific Data Extension every time this button is clicked in the email? or trigger a automatic email when the user clicks in the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AMPScript is server-side only, you would need to have this button go to a Landing Page / Cloud Page and use scripting there to upsert into a DE or trigger the email.

AMPScript offers functions for both of these - [UPSERTDATA()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm) and  [Triggered Send via API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/triggeredSendOYB.htm)

There are some [SSJS options](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_coreLibraryFunctions.htm) as well.

If you need to have it on a 3rd party site, you would need to utilize the [API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm) to accomplish this.